# Websphere with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, websphere

Is it practical (or possible) to create a Websphere Portlet for a Classic ASP website?

Answer (score 2):

Websphere is Java based, but you can mix any web content using IFRAMEs or Ajax to inject HTML in your ASP page.

Practical? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, but you would still need to have seperate hosting environments for your Java Portlets and your IIS ASP applications, even if called within an IFrame.